# URL is not redirecting to homepage in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, redirect

I have a strange issue with my site. When I Try to load my site with its url, it permanenently redirect to product view page of a particular product in my site. The situation is like this.

Let my site url be `www.mydomain.com`. When I trying to load this url, it is redirecting to `www.mydomain.com/particular-product?crc=110` (an example). The product to which url redirecting seems to be changing in time basis.

I have checked in `system -> config` and checked in web section.`secure url` and `unsecure url` are given correctly there. Then I check home page layout section and made sure that there   is no redirection codes

Then I checked `index.php` and it also seems good. No redirection codes. I have checked `.httaccess`. There is however redirection is set to on. But no code found that redirect basic url to any product.

What should I do now.. in order to  load my home page when url is loaded on addressbar. Please help me friends... It makes me crazy.. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you create multi store ?

Comment: If yes then change the store view and check the secure and unsecure url

Comment: @KeyulShah. no there is only one store view `default` for my site

Comment: Please note before this I have added a theme for my site.

Comment: Reindex n clear cache then try

Comment: ok will make a trY. Is there any other ways to set redirection in magento?

Comment: Yes in catlog >> tab in admin panel

Comment: I can see lot of entry there for lot of products

Comment: What is the value of 
Web > Default Pages > Default Web URL?

Comment: Also, check your Rewrite rules for a request path of /

Comment: @benmarks : it is set to home page. My problem is not solved yet. When I made url rewrite to off though admin and tried to load `www.mydomain.com/index.php` it redirected to product page. But it is on, it loads the same page, means home page. Does it make any sense?

Comment: @CCBlackburn :Where should I check for it?

Comment: "Default Web URL" cannot be set to "home page". It's a string input, typically just `cms`.

Comment: @benmarks : sorry.it set to `cms`. I have written a custom url redirection like this. `request path:/` and `targeted path:home`. Now when I load `www.mydomain.com` it loads `www.mydomain.com/home`. It solved my problem temporally. But if I want to load www.domain.com/home when try to load `mydomain.com` and also I want url look like `www.mydomain.com`,what should I do then?

Comment: In Admin -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management. I'd sort the request path and see if it comes up

Comment: @programmer_rkt any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem, after trying everything listed above and on several other SO answers 
i discovered there is more than one base_url definition in the core_config_data table

if you run

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%'
```

You should see all of the definitions
the scope was different on this definition and was overriding the default which i had already changed.

Comment: thanks for this answer. howerver it is impossible to test this. because that project is over in late past. +1 for this. coz its a good solution.